# what the difference between item: {$exists:false} and item : null?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What is the difference by doing :

```
"AnArray.fieldA":null
```

and

```
"AnArray.fieldA":{$exists:false}
```

And why on documents like

```
{
  AnArray:[
    {},
    {fieldA:1}
  ]
},

{
  AnArray:[
    {fieldA:3},
    {fieldA:1}
  ]
}
```

`"AnArray.fieldA":null` return me the first one doc but `"AnArray.fieldA":{$exists:false}` return me **no doc :(**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nicely explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/index.html#type0).

> The { item : null } query matches documents that either contain the item field whose value is null or that do not contain the item field.

So your first query returns the document if there's any subdocument in `AnArray` with missing `fieldA`

`$exists` works in a different way. `"AnArray.fieldA"` is interpreted as an array of values taken from specified path. For your documents it is:  `[null, 1]` and `[3,1]`. So as long as there's at least one `fieldA` `$exists` will return `true` and as you expect it to return `false` you're getting no results.

Comment: thanks! but I don't understand why it is interpreted as [null, 1] and [3,1] instead of [1] and [3,1]! Is it not a bug ?

Comment: @loki that's by design, since you have two documents it returns 2-element array. As there's no value in first doc it "interpolates" it into `null`